# Tk filedialog prevents focus of entries

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

After using tk.filedialog, the entry field cannot be selected for roughly a minute and focus_set will not work on the entry field during that duration. After ~1 min, the entry fields can be used. Without calling tk.filedialog the entry works as expected.

minimal functional code that still contains the issue:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.filedialog

class MyApp(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        cur_file = tk.filedialog.askopenfilename(title = "Open file")
        entry = tk.Entry(root, width=30, textvariable = "50")
        entry.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master) 

root = tk.Tk()
myapp = MyApp(master = root)
myapp.mainloop()
```

Is there any way to increase the responsiveness?

Kind regards

checking the focus with print("cur focus is on:", root.focus_get())during the first minute returns:

```
cur focus is on: None
```

after that first minute it returns

```
cur focus is on: .!entry1
```

Comment: ***take 30-60s***: How long to read the XML, **without**. creating any Widget?

Comment: The problem occures even with the above shown xml snipped, but even with the normal xml, load time is under a second until the tkinter window is fully populated with the content read from the xml. The Tkinter program loads quickly, and everything besides the Entry works. The buttons work and also the save button works straightaway.

Comment: Are you running this on windows?

Comment: @tasmo **1.** Use a `__main__` entry point. **2.** Remove the fildialog from `__init__`. **3.** Call `tk.Frame.__init__(...` as the first Statement!

Comment: @ Bryan. Yes, running on Windows 10. @ stovfl Unfortunately, none of those changes made any difference.